# python-gitlab how to get page source?

Tags: python, gitlab, python-gitlab

I have accessed a gitlab page using private_token.

I now have a Gitlab object.

```
>>> gl
<gitlab.Gitlab object at 0x011052F0>
```

How can I retrieve the page source content of the page I'm currently on? I can't find anything in the documentation... :(

I've used this command `print(str(gl.__dict__).replace(',','\n'))` to get the attributes of the Gitlab object, but there is nothing helpful there that I can see.

There doesn't seem to be much on SO around Gitlab. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to access?

The API is well documented here: https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-objects.html

This API is designed to bring Python object-oriented design to your interactions with GitLab. For example, to get a list of projects:

```py
for gl.projects.list(iterator=True):
    print(project.name)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it's been so long ago that I can't remember what I was trying to do there :D